# Create table of content inside table

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, tableofcontents, docutils, toctree

I want to be able to generate table of content inside a table. E.g. it should
have borders and look like this:

```
.. tabularcolumns:: |p{10.5cm}|p{1.1cm}|p{1.4cm}|p{1.1cm}|
+----------------------------------------------------+-------+---------+-----+
|                                                    | hw1   |  hw2    | hw3 |
+====================================================+=======+=========+=====+
| heading 1                                          |       |         |     |
+----------------------------------------------------+-------+---------+-----+
| heading 2                                          |       |         |     |
+----------------------------------------------------+-------+---------+-----+
| heading 3                                          |       |         |     |
+----------------------------------------------------+-------+---------+-----+
```

I want to auto-generate the table from something like:

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

file 1
file 2
```

The output is both html and pdf.

Can this be done? Or do I have to use the docutils parser or similar?

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the basic.css to give your `toc` a border:

Step 1: From your Sphinx build directory `cp _build/html/_static/basic.css _static/`

Step 2: Add the following line to basic.css

```
div.toctree-wrapper {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

div.toctree-wrapper li {
    padding: 1px 8px 1px 5px;
    border:1px solid black; 
}
```

Step 3: Edit one of your rst files so that build kicks in when you execute `make html`

.. And you should see borders around your table of contents ... Like This
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I need to output both html-pages and a pdf-document.